# How to retrieve data from SQL Server?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

I was wondering why my query is returning null when I know there is data there.

**my query is as follows:**

```
if (isset($_POST['noteid'])) 
    {
        $showNoteInfo = "SELECT Note FROM Notes WHERE NoteID = 2";
        $showNotes    = sqlsrv_query($conn, $showNoteInfo);

        var_dump($showNotes);
    }
```

I have tested `$_POST['noteid']` and that displays an ID no problem, in theory this id will replace where I have the number 2 in my query.

However I know in my table in the Notes table where NoteID = 2 the text should be like this [image]

However `var_dump` displays "*resource(7) of type (SQL Server Statement)*"

And I have also tried a different method of displaying it and that returned as the query expected resource and was given NULL, so why is this query not getting any results?

My connection details are in an include at the top of the page and are like this: http://pastebin.com/qz3tScdW

If you need anything else please ask.

Underlying question, why is my Query returning NULL when I know theres data there?

Comment: `sqlsrv_query` returns a statement resource on successful queries. You then need to [fetch the result](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-fetch.php) from it before you can do anything with it.

Comment: Check out the example in the documentation I linked.

Comment: `resource(7) of type (SQL Server Statement)` != `NULL`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never actually try to retrieve your data. [`sqlsrv_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-query.php) performs the database query, but it doesn't get the data. You need to use [`sqlsrv_fetch_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-fetch-array.php) (or [`sqlsrv_fetch_object`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-fetch-object.php)) for that:

```
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $showNoteInfo);

if (sqlsrv_has_rows($stmt)) {
    $data = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
    var_dump($data['Note']);
} else {
    echo "No data found";
}
```

Comment: I tried

<?php

    if (isset($_POST['noteid'])) 
    {
        if (empty($_POST['noteid'])) 
        {
            $notes = 'No Data';
        }
        else if (sqlsrv_has_rows($showNotes)) 
        {
            $notes = sqlsrv_fetch_object($showNotes, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
            var_dump($showNotes['Note']);
        }
        else
        {
            echo("No Data");
        }
    }
?>

and it returned as NULL in the dump

Comment: @LukeLitherland And did you try with `sqlsrv_fetch_array`?

Comment: Yep, still returning "NULL" its really strange

Comment: @LukeLitherland Try the actual code in my answer. You will see that you need to use the result of the `sqlsrv_fetch_array` call, not the `$showNotes`. In my code, that is `$data['Notes']`; in yours it is `$notes['Notes']`.

Comment: OMg thank you so much! That worked one last little thing, why is it displaying the string and character amount at the start of the text like, string(256) then in "" marks it has the text?

Comment: @LukeLitherland That's how `var_dump` works. It tells you what kind of value it is, then what the value of the variable is.

Comment: Ah brilliant so i could change that to an echo so that i could display the result in a div now? once again big thanks!